# Is there a Java IDE that supports the same package and class names?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

everybody. I have a Java Eclipse project. It contains many packages, and the class names can be the same with the package, just like:

```
org.a
  a.java <--------- this class is org.a.a
  b.java
org.b
  a.java
org.a.a <---------- this package is also org.a.a
  a.java
  b.java
```

When compiling the project, Eclipse reports error: The type "xxx" collides with a package. So is there a Java IDE that supports the same package and class names? Or is there a way I can compile it just in Eclipse?

Comment: I'm not sure what's in your "a.java" file, but in there have you explicitly specified the package you are referring to. For example, maybe you have a class called "test" in the file 'a.java'; then to refer to it in your code, are you calling "org.a.a.test"? And also do an import of "org.a.a.test" in the file.

Comment: The short answer is no, if you have classes in different packages with the same name you will need to use their absolute names (package.name) to reference them in your code, this is the point of having package name spaces.  So in your code you would need to use `org.a.a` and `org.a.a.a` explicitly, rather than using the `import` statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, if you have classes in different packages with the same name you will need to use their absolute names (package.name) to reference them in your code, this is the point of having package name spaces.

So in your code you would need to use `org.a.a` and `org.a.a.a` explicitly, rather than using the `import` statement...

For example...

```
org.a.a a1 = new org.a.a();
org.a.a.a a2 = new org.a.a.a();
```

Comment: But the classes in the jar file can tolerate the same names of package and class, right? Is there a software to rename classes in a jar, so I can use Eclipse to compile it? iF not, how can I write such a software by myself?

Comment: Yes, but classes in Jars are stored in their package directories.  No, you can rename them.  To use them, you need to reference the class you want via an absolute reference, as demonstrated and yes, we do this all the time...Look at `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`

Comment: Is there a programmatical way to rename the symbols (like package names, class names) in the classes (jar), we know Eclipse can rename using the refactoring when no compile errors occurred, but I have errors now, so I can't use Eclipse. This program contains so many classes, so it is difficult to change them mannually

Comment: You can't really go about modifying the byte code in this way (or at least you shouldn't).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Eclipse issue, it is a Java feature.

[The Java Language Specification makes the following restrictions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.1)

> The **members** of a package are its **subpackages** and all the **top level
>   class types** (§7.6, §8 (Classes)) and top level interface types (§9
>   (Interfaces)) declared in all the compilation units (§7.3) of the
>   package.

and

> A package **may not contain two members of the same name**, or a
>   **compile-time error** results.

In your example, `org.a` is a package. You want it to have two members: the type `org.a.a` and the package `org.a.a`. **The Java Language does not allow this.**

---

Java conventions state that your package names should start with a lowecase letter while your type names should start with an uppercase letter. If you follow these conventions, such problems will never arise.

Comment: But the classes in the jar file can tolerate the same names of package and class, right? Is there a software to rename classes in a jar, so I can use Eclipse to compile it? iF not, how can I write such a software by myself?

Comment: @hsluoyz No they shouldn't. If the JAR was created manually, maybe. But the compiler should never have allowed it. **This is a Java limitation.**